# Javascript - Split array into two, create <div><a> using new arrays for href and innerHTML

Tags: javascript, arrays

Fairly new to Javascript and trying a more complex script (to me, anyway).

The end-game for this script is the following:

1. Element tagged with onclick=(runscript) will prompt script to load a text file of site names/links, separated by commas.
2. Script loads text file into an array.
3. First loop iterates through array, separating the main array into two new arrays based on even/odd array position. (ex. Site name is 0, link is 1, name is 2, link is 3, etc.)
4. Second loop iterates through the site name array, creating a new div element for each value in the array.
5. Second loop also creates new anchor element, appending it to the div element.
6. Second loop sets div's class, anchor's href, and appends the new div to a container div.

I feel like I'm making a few noob mistakes and my lack of exposure to Javascript is keeping me from seeing them. I cut out the first two steps to test steps 3-6 instead.

This is what I've managed to come up with so far.. any nudge in the right direction would be awesome.

Thanks!

```js
var main = ["Google", "http://google.com", 'Gmail', 'http://gmail.com', 'Hotmail', 'http://hotmail.com', 'Battle.net', 'http://battle.net', 'Steam', 'http://steampowered.com'];

function getSites() {
    var site = new Array();
    var link = new Array();
    
    for (var i = 0; i <= main.length; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            link.push(main[i]);
        } else {
            site.push(main[i]);
        }
    }
    for ($i = 1; i <= site.length; i++) {
        var divElement = document.createElement("div");
        var anchorElement = document.createElement("a");
        divElement.appendChild(anchorElement);
        divElement.className = "boxin";
        anchorElement.href = link[i];
        divElement.innerHTML = (site[i]);
        
        linkContainer.appendChild(divElement);
    }

}

getSites();
```

```css
boxin {
    height: 20px;
    background-color: green;
}

#linkContainer div
{
    border:solid 1px black;
    margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="linkContainer"></div>
```

Comment: You have a typo in the second loop... `for (var i = 0; i < site.length; i++) {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a bug in the second iteration, you are initializing a new variable `$i`, but the condition is checking for `i<=site.length` which will be false since the value of `i` is updated to `main.length` at the end of the first loop

But you really don't need to use 2 loop to solve the problem, you can use a single loop as below. Also you need to set the label text as the content of anchor element not of the div

```js
var main = ["Google", "http://google.com", 'Gmail', 'http://gmail.com', 'Hotmail', 'http://hotmail.com', 'Battle.net', 'http://battle.net', 'Steam', 'http://steampowered.com'];

function getSites() {
  for (var i = 0; i < main.length; i += 2) {
    var divElement = document.createElement("div");
    var anchorElement = document.createElement("a");
    divElement.appendChild(anchorElement);
    divElement.className = "boxin";
    anchorElement.href = main[i + 1];
    anchorElement.innerHTML = (main[i]);

    linkContainer.appendChild(divElement);
  }

}

getSites();
```

```css
boxin {
  height: 20px;
  background-color: green;
}
#linkContainer div {
  border: solid 1px black;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="linkContainer"></div>
```

Comment: Wow. I can't believe I overlooked that. It's making the divs and appending them properly now. The innerHTML seems to work as well. Guess I just need to figure out why I'm getting 'undefined' divs now. Seriously, thank you.

edit: Hah, I geeked out and changed my code before looking at your single loop. That's much simpler than what I was doing.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need them to be in an array? I think an object would work much better.

```
var sites = {
  "Google": "http://google.co.uk",
  "Gmail": "http://gmail.com"
};
```

Then you could loop through the object and achieve what you wanted.

Comment: I don't believe it _has_ to be an array, but my ideas have been limited by my toolset. I think I settled on an array while researching step 2.

Answer (score 0):

Try it : i'm change your code little bit... below code 100% workable...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="../js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        boxin {
            height: 20px;
            background-color: green;
        }

        #linkContainer div {
            border: solid 1px black;
            margin: 5px;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>


        <div>
            <div id="linkContainer"></div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">


            var main = ["Google", "http://google.com", 'Gmail', 'http://gmail.com', 'Hotmail', 'http://hotmail.com', 'Battle.net', 'http://battle.net', 'Steam', 'http://steampowered.com'];

            function getSites() {
                var site = new Array();
                var link = new Array();

                for (var i = 0; i <= main.length; i++) {
                    if (i % 2 == 0) {
                        link.push(main[i]);
                    } else {
                        site.push(main[i]);
                    }
                }
                for (var i = 0; i < site.length; i++) {
                    var divElement = document.createElement("div");
                    var anchorElement = document.createElement("a");
                    divElement.appendChild(anchorElement);
                    divElement.className = "boxin";
                    anchorElement.href = link[i];
                    divElement.innerHTML = (site[i]);
                    document.getElementById("linkContainer").appendChild(divElement);

                }

            }

            getSites();

        </script>

</body>
</html>
```